# VS2017 not attaching to unity app on android - Shows in list, nothing happens when selected

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I am unable to attach VS2017 to my unity android app. Here's my setup.

I have adb connected via wifi.

> C:\Users\Diamonds\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
>   List of devices attached
>   192.168.86.20:5555      device

Unity successfully sends the build to the android phone, and logs show up when the app runs on phone:
[image: unity logs]

I've got the app just running on the phone. Inside VS2017 the phone shows up correctly. When I select it, VS2017 spins for 20 seconds then does nothing. No error in VS2017 or in Unity.

[image: attach to android phone in vs2017 does nothing]

Oddly I do not have the phone connected via USB. I do not know why it shows up there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try USB instead of WIFI.
According to Microsoft's documentation

> Wifi is versatile but super slow compared to USB because of latency. We saw a lack of proper multicast support for some routers or devices (Nexus series are well known for this).

using USB is a better option.

ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/visualstudio/cross-platform/troubleshooting-and-known-issues-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2017